# Android: Problems with VD launching from cmd

Tags: android, eclipse, proxy

I have a problem with launching my VD from cmd, I'm using Eclipse Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
Build id: M20130204-1200

And when I want to launch my emulator with proxy, because I can't get Internet on it...
I launch VD from cmd with command - `C:\Users\user\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools>emulator -avd phone -http-proxy 219.69.104.232:8080` but when I hit Enter it gives me an error - `creating window 27 27 480 854
FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:89:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). f
d 1036 max1024
Error accepting connection, aborting`

So how I can launch my VD with proxy settings for Internet working in all phone?

Comment: have onyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem twice: first time it happened, I fixed it by adding `-no-audio` to my AVD arguments.

Second time around, even the first fix didn't work. It only got fixed when I freed up some memory in the host PC (it has 8 GB RAM, but I had to close teamviewer).